# How do I pass mysql database content to a different page?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to display my database content to an ejs web page. However, I am running into a problem when trying to pass the content between pages.

I have a JavaScript page `"store.js"` which has the server running:

**store.js-**

```
var express = require('express');
var dbcon = require('./app/db/databaseconnection');
//var path = require('path');
//dbcon.connection;

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

dbcon.connect();
console.log(dbcon.getproducts());

//var filepath = path.join(__dirname, '../../views/')
var filepath = __dirname + '/views/';
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/', router);

router.get('/', (request, response) => response.render(filepath + 'index', { page_name: 'home' }));
router.get('/store', (request, response) => response.render(filepath + 'store', { page_name: 'store' }));
router.get('/about', (request, response) => response.render(filepath + 'about', { page_name: 'about' }));
router.get('/contact', (request, response) => response.render(filepath + 'contact', { page_name: 'contact' }));
router.get('/build', (request, response) => response.render(filepath + 'build/build'));
router.get('/learn', (request, response) => response.render(filepath + 'learn/learn'));
app.use('*', (request, response) => response.render(filepath + '404', { page_name: '404' }));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server running at Port 3000"));
```

Then I have a JavaScript page which includes the database connection:

**databaseconnection.js-**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(conObject = {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "LOTOS123l",
    database: "dbComputerStore"
});


module.exports = {
    connect: () => 
    { 
        connection.connect((error) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(conObject.database + " connected!");
        });
    },
    // The display method prints the returned result to the console.
    // Change this to return the result. Maybe a toString() ?
    getproducts: () => {
        /*var result = */connection.query('SELECT * FROM products', (error, result) => { 
            return result;
            //return result;
            // console.log(result);
            // How to get certain properties
            // console.log(result[0].brand);
            // console.log(result[0].series);
            // console.log(result[0].model);
        });
        //return result.result;
    },
    createdb: () => {

    },
    createtable: () => {

    },
    populatetable: () => {

    }
}
```

So on the `store.js` page I have the `console.log(dbcon.getproducts());` Which I was hoping would display the database content of the `"products"` table. However I keep getting undefined. Basically, I can't get it to pass from the database connection page to the store.js page.

If I get this to work, my next step would be to find a way to display the products table to an ejs page. I've been trying to solve this for a while now so any help would be appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: `connection.query` is an async function, you either need to pass the result to caller through a callback (provided by the caller) or modify `getproducts` to return a Promise and wait for the promise to resolve in store.js and then display the output

Comment: Which way would you recommend?

Comment: Both approaches should work fine. Also note that connecting to the database is an async operation. You'll have to wait (using a callback or Promise) for the connection to become ready before querying the database. I suggest you to create a connection pool, and each time you want to query the database (ie. in getproducts method), get a connection from the pool, query the database using that connection and return the result (by calling a callback or resolving a promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up my comments, here's how you can modify **databaseconnection.js** module to use a [connection pool](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) and return query results via [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

**Note: the code is mostly untested**

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10, // adjust this according to your needs
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "LOTOS123l",
  database: "dbComputerStore"
});

module.exports = {
  // you don't need the connect method anymore

  getProducts: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM products", (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(results);
      }
    });
  }),
  // ...
};
```

then in **store.js**, you can do:

```
const dbcon = require('./app/db/databaseconnection');

dbcon.getProducts()
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

// or you could use async/await syntax:

const asyncFn = async () => {
  try {
    const results = await dbcon.getProducts();
    console.log(results);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
asyncFn();
```

Comment: I'm getting DeprecationWarning: timers.enroll() is deprecated. Please use setTimeout instead.

Comment: Searching the exact same warning string in [`mysql` module repository on GitHub](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) leads you to [this (currently resolved) issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2003). So basically you need to upgrade `mysql` module to the latest version (**2.16.0** as of now).

Comment: Ok thanks, Last thing, The result is displayed as Array(1) [RowDataPacket], how would I get the Content in the Array?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work, I just used a for loop and it displayed all the content. Thank You Very Much!